how to create deployment package with s3 bucket in chalice
i created github action workflow to deploy chalice application it shows following error:
Invalid bucket name "": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:(s3|s3-object-lambda):[a-z\-0-9]*:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-.]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$"
Creating deployment package.
Updating policy for IAM role: test-app-prod-user
Updating lambda function: test-app-prod-prod-handle_s3_event
Configuring S3 events in bucket  to function test-app-prod-prod-handle_s3_event```

